# Sort 2dim vector and keep indices

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I filled a 2dim vector as below:

```
vector< vector<double>> save;
for ( int i=0;i<5;i++ )
{
    for ( int j=0;j<5;j++ )
    {
        save[i][j]=i*(i+j);

    }
  }
```

Now how can I sort it and keep their related indices ?
For example indices of 8 are 4 and 4

I have already used this code to save indices and sort them in two other array which 2dim and 1dim respectively

```
void sort(int index[5][2],int order[5])
 {
     int l=0;
     while( l<5)
     {
  float max=-10000;
  int c1=0;
  int c2=0;
     for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<5;j++)
        {
            if(save[i][j]>max)
            {
                max=save[i][j];
                c1=i+1;
                c2=j+1;
            }

        }
    }

    order[l]=max;
    index[l][0]=c1;
    index[l][1]=c2;



    l++;
}
 }
```

I want to know can I save more time in case of computation time if I use vector and sort function instead of current solution when number of data is 100 instead of 5 ?

Comment: **For example indices of 8 are 4 and 4**. What do you mean? You want to store two sets of data for previous values?

Comment: @Aesthete: i mean that for example here save[1][1]=2 i want to keep value of i and j which are 1 and 1 after sorting (they belong to 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this.

```
// Create a structure to manage co-ordinates, values, and 1d-indices.
// These are the components you're actually interested in.
struct PointValue
{
    PointValue(int x, int y, int value)
        : x(x), y(t), value(value), indexOneDimensional(x*(x+y))
    {}
    int x, y, indexOneDimensional;
    int value;
    // Sort predicate for sorting these PointValue objects.
    static bool SortFunction(const PointValue& left, const PointValue& right)
    {
        return left.value < right.value;
    }
};
typedef std::vector<PointValue> PointValueList;


int sizeX = 100; int sizeY = 100;
PointValueList myValues(sizeX * sizeY);

// Create a 100x100 array with random values for each point.
for (int i = 0; i < sizeX; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeY; j++)
    {
        myValues.push_back(PointValue(i, j, rand()));
    }
}

// Sort using our static predicate.
std::sort(myValues.begin(), myValues.end(), PointValue::SortFunction);

// Print 1d-indices.
std::for_each(m_values.begin(), m_values.end(), [](const PointValue& val) {
    printf("Index is: %d. Value is: %d", val.indexOneDimensional, val.value);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hash map of numbers to their indices. Something like:

```
std::map< double, std::list<int> > indices;
```

Also, take into account the fact that the comparison between two floating point numbers is approximate.